# My login form returns the same form after authentication,my LDAP connection is not working

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I need to create a login page with login form with LDAP connection. After correct authentication user should be redirect to another profile page. For this purposes I have created two files.First one with the form and LDAP connection, the second one is re-directive page.  In practice I feel the blanks and the same empty contact form appears. When I take a part of my code connected with LDAP on the after `<?php get_header(); ?>` the login form is not visible on the page.

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <h1 class="text-center login-title">Sign in to continue to Bootsnipp</h1>
            <div class="account-wall">
                <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120"
                    alt="">
                <form class="form-signin" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                    Sign in</button>
                <label class="checkbox pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                    Remember me
                </label>
                <a href="#" class="pull-right need-help">Need help? </a><span class="clearfix"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="text-center new-account">Create an account </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
// active directory server
 $ldap = ldap_connect("ldap://44.44.444");


//active directory DN (base location of ldap search)
$ldap = 'dc=itit,dc=local';


// configure ldap params
 ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
 ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);

// user prefix
  $ldap_usr_dom = "@itit.local";


    // verify user and password
 if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {

echo success;
}else{
return false;
}

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: `ldap://44.44.444` - Is that the address you're actually using? That's not a valid IP address. Also, having `return` like that in your `else`-block will stop the page from rendering anything after it in that file.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. No it's not my actual IP address

Comment: You're storing the ldap connection in `$ldap`, but in the line after the connection, you're overwriting the variable `$ldap` with a string. After that, you can't use the variable `$ldap` as the connection in the other ldap-functions anymore. While developing, you should make sure that you have error reporting turned on (use `E_ALL`) and that you have display errors turned on as well. This code should give you a bunch of errors and warnings.

Comment: can you recommend me a code that will work,please, because I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: I've already pointed out several things that might be your problem. Fix those and see what happens. Don't forget the error reporint and display errors. Adding that will most likely give you more info. That's basic debugging (which is a major part of the development process)

Comment: Thank you so much. I did what you said and It helped me.